# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level why? I have an hour

Tags: python

When I compile the Python code below, I get 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level# main module

```
def main(): 

      # Local variables 
        weight = 0.0 
        shipping = 0.0 

      # Get package weight 

        weight = int(input("Enter the weight of the package: "))

      # Calculate the shipping charge 


       if weight < 2:
            shipping_charge = '$1.10'
       elif weight > 2 and weight < 6:
            shipping_charge = '$2.20'
       elif weight > 6 and weight < 10:
            shipping_charge = '$3.70'
       elif weight > 10:
            shipping_charge = '$3.80'

     # print shipping charge 
       showShipping(shipping) 


     print("Shipping charge:", shipping_charge)
```

Why?

Comment: check your indentation.

Comment: The last line seems to be off.

Answer (score 5):

Re-indent everything and make sure you've converted your tabs to spaces. Then make sure all the "spaces" are at the proper indentation level. The difference can cause such error messages.

In python, everything inside of a given block must be at the same indentation level, whether it be four or five or (insert personal favorite number of spaces here).

Heres a good reference: [Python docs on indentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html)

Note: From what you have posted on SO, the last print statement seems to be less indented than the rest. That should be the first thing to double check after doing the above.

Comment: +1 for tab to spaces. That's an easy one to miss.